# Почему у меня в django rest framework нет кнопки для динамического добавления вложенных данных формы, если должна быть?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, сериализация, django-model

Прошу о помощи

Взгляните на скрин пожалуйста, не могу понять почему не могу добавлять links динамически:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Вот такой вид данных формата Json должен получиться:*

```json
values {
    "firstname": "l",
    "lastname": "m",
    "links": [
        {
          "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
          "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
        },
        {
          "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
          "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

И к тому же даже если вот эти все существующие поля заполнить(ну то есть те поля, которые уже есть  в django rest framework, а именно - один массив links и Имя вместе с Фамилией) выводится ошибка:

> The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
> Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `schedule.serializers.WorkSuperSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

Я перебирала очень много вариантов решения проблемы, например объявляла метод `create()`:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    links_data = validated_data.pop('links')
    worksuper = WorkSuper.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for link_data in links_data:
        Link.objects.create(worksuper=worksuper, **link_data)
    return worksuper
```

Но ошибка как была, так и есть.

**Вообще вот мой код:**

`Models.py:`

```
class WorkSuper(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=10, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=30, blank=True)
class Link(models.Model):
    links = models.ForeignKey(WorkSuper, related_name='links', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    linkname = models.CharField("linkname", max_length=100, blank=True)
    linkurl = models.CharField("linkurl", max_length=100, blank=True)
```

`Serializers.py:`

```
class WorkSuperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    links = LinkSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = WorkSuper
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'links')
        # depth = 1

        def create(self, validated_data):
            links_data = validated_data.pop('links')
            worksuper = WorkSuper.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for link_data in links_data:
                Link.objects.create(worksuper=worksuper, **link_data)
            return worksuper
        # def to_representation(self, instance):
        #     data = super().to_representation(instance)
        #     data['links']['links'] = instance.inner.link
        #     # return super().to_representation(instance)
        #     return data
```

`Views.py:`

```
class WorkSuperView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = WorkSuperSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = WorkSuper.objects.all()
       return queryset

   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       queryset = self.get_queryset()
       serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
       data = serializer.data
       # return JsonResponse({'data': data})
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

Получается вот такой json при заполнении формы (скрин ниже), то есть `links` пустые:

[image: Links is empty]

Я надеюсь на помощь, потому что уже долго не могу разобраться.

Заранее спасибо
Помогите пожалуйста

Я действительно очень очень долго уже не могу с этим справиться, перечитала уже просто все.